# how to format a string result consisting of 10 heats in total with 0 and the desired value

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I have to insert the results of a query into a string of ten characters (numbers). The values must all be 0 and I need to replace only the last characters with those of the query cells.

My code:

```
Dim idClienteCosarConsorziati As New DataSet
idClienteCosarConsorziati = DB_SQL.OpenDataset("SELECT Anagrafica.ID_cliente FROM Anagrafica WHERE (((Anagrafica.ID_gruppo) Is Null) AND ((Anagrafica.ID_padre_consorzio)=13584))", "Anagrafica.ID_cliente")

Try
    Dim contenitore As DataTable = idClienteCosarConsorziati.Tables(0)
    For Each row As DataRow In contenitore.Rows
        For Each cells As String In row.ItemArray
            Dim stringtoserach As String = "E:\PDF_Fatture\" + Format(cells, "0000000000")
        Next
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I try with `Format(cells, "0000000000")` but the result does not have the 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String already has a function [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-5.0)

```vb
cells.PadLeft(10, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the smiliar task using this: More info about Right is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function)

```
Right('0000000000'+cells , 10)
```

Comment: Right is from the old vb Strings class. It is best to learn and use methods from the String class.

Comment: thanks for feedback. it was something from my production code :)